# Form in Ruby on Rails: using find and create by in the model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, model, rails-activerecord

**Does "find_or_create_by" is the key to my problem?**

**Answer** No! Below is another suggestion that works.

I took over a system. It manages courses and their participants. In accordance to a course in a certain form a user can enter his personal data like name, where he works (institution) etc.

The relavant tables:

- courses
- particpants
- persons
- institutions

When the user hits enter in this form

1. a new participant should be created (id, person_id, course_id)
2. a new person should be created (id, institution_id, prename, surname, etc.)
3. a new institution sould be created (id, description etc.)

**The following does work**

When the user hits enter:

1. a new institution is created (id, description etc.)
2. a new person is created with the right institution id (id, institution_id etc.)

The following does not work:

1. no new corresponding participant (id, person_id, course_id) is created

I am very new to Rails. But I guess in the person model (below) the def **institution_description**
leads to the creation of the records in the institution table and person table(?). But I am really not sure.

**Code of the Person model**

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :institution
  attr_accessible :institution_id,:title,:prename,:surname,:street,:street_number,:zip_code,:city,:phone,:fax,:email,:institution_description
  has_many :participants


def institution_description
    institution.description if institution
end

def institution_description=(description)
    self.institution = Institution.find_or_create_by_description(description) unless description.blank?
end
```

My thought is I could use a similar def like **course_id** in the participant model (?). If a course_id is given then create a participant. But I am not sure how I would have to use **course_id** correctly (If this even works this way)

**Code of Participant model**

```
class Participant < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :course
  belongs_to :function
  has_one :person


  attr_accessible :course_id, :function_id, :person_id, course_id


def course_id
    participant.course_id if participant
end

def course_id=(course_id)
  self.participant = Participant.find_or_create_by_course_id(course_id) unless trial_id.blank?
end
```

**Code of the form**

```
<%= form_for(@person) do |f| %>
<fieldset>
  <div class="table">
    <div class="tr">
      <div class="th">
        <%= f.label t(:institution) %>
      </div>
      <div class="tdsep">:</div>
      <div class="td">
        <%= f.autocomplete_field :institution_description, autocomplete_institution_description_persons_path %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tr">
      <div class="th">
        <%= f.label t(:title) %>
      </div>
      <div class="tdsep">:</div>
      <div class="td">
        <%= f.text_field :title %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tr">
      <div class="th">
        <%= f.label :prename, t(:prename_html, :url => Rails.configuration.staffsearch) %>
      </div>
      <div class="tdsep">:</div>
      <div class="td">
        <%= f.text_field :prename %>
      </div>
    </div> #etc...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set up a relationship between `Person` and `Course`

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :organization
  attr_accessible :institution_id,:title,:prename,:surname,:street,:street_number,:zip_code,:city,:phone,:fax,:email,:institution_description
  has_many :participants
  has_many :courses, through: :participants
```

Then in your controller create method you can do...

```
@person.courses << @course
```

(assuming that your current course is in an instance variable, or if not modify as needed)

This will automatically create the `Participant` record when you save the `User`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I set up the relationship as recommended. But I don't understand the second part. Do you mean in the `Participant` controllers create method I can write `@participant.courses << @course`? Because if so this doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: I should've said `@person` not `@user` and I've now changed that.  Is your course object available as `@course`?  Also, in future messages or posts please be specific about error messages... "doesn't work unfortunately" is not very useful.

Comment: Because of the `through` relationship, Rails knows to create a Participant record if it needs to associated a course with a person.

Comment: Ok, I will keep that in mind! I now added in the  `Person` controller `@person.courses << @course` and now I get an error message `undefined method courses' for #<Person:0xa176d1c>`. Earlier I didn`t get an error message because in two tables records where created. I am not yet familiar enough with rails. So I don't know what you mean with "assuming that your current course is in an instance variable".

Comment: First. Thank you! I had a typo. It now creates a participant! But oddly its `id`starts at 10000. The very next is 10001. Note that there have already been participants in this table. The last one was No 3646. Do you know why that is?

Comment: No, that weirdness has nothing to do with the solution.  Have you been doing anything to control id value?  The id should be unique but otherwise meaningless and it's not a good idea to try to assign a characteristic to it.